# A matrix exponential identity

Tags: solution-verification, matrix-exponential

In a physics textbook, the following identity was claimed to hold
$$
e^{A+B} = e^{A} + \int_0^1 e^{\lambda(A+B)} B e^{(1-\lambda)A} d\lambda
$$
with $A$ and $B$ both being complex matrices which do not necessarily commute. I have tried to convince myself of this identity by considering
$$
\begin{align}
  \frac{d}{d\lambda} e^{A+\lambda B}
  &= B e^{A+\lambda B} \left( = e^{A+\lambda B}B \right)\\
  e^{A+B} - e^A
  &= \int_0^1 B e^{A+\lambda B} d\lambda \\
  e^{A+B}
  &= e^A + \int_0^1 B e^{\lambda (A+B) + (1-\lambda) A} d\lambda \\
  &\stackrel{?}{=} e^A + \int_0^1 B e^{\lambda (A+B)} e^{(1-\lambda) A} d\lambda \\  
  &= e^A + \int_0^1 e^{\lambda (A+B)} B e^{(1-\lambda) A} d\lambda \\  
\end{align}
$$
where I have marked the dubious step with "?". Am I wrong to think this step incorrect, or is there an alternative way to the result?